# Using ax.twinx() with sns.FacetGrid and sns.lineplot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to apply a shared x-axis on each facet plot with `'total_bill'` on the left y-axis, and `'tip'` on the right y-axis. Using the `tips` dataframe to demonstrate.

**The following dataset `tip` is used:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today= datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(tips.shape[0]-1), freq='D')
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips['date'] = days
```

**Dataset preview:**

```
tips.head()
```

|  | total_bill | tip | sex | smoker | day | time | size | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 16.99 | 1.01 | Female | No | Sun | Dinner | 2 | 2021-01-19 16:39:38.363600 |
| 1 | 10.34 | 1.66 | Male | No | Sun | Dinner | 3 | 2021-01-20 16:39:38.363600 |
| 2 | 21.01 | 3.5 | Male | No | Sun | Dinner | 3 | 2021-01-21 16:39:38.363600 |
| 3 | 23.68 | 3.31 | Male | No | Sun | Dinner | 2 | 2021-01-22 16:39:38.363600 |
| 4 | 24.59 | 3.61 | Female | No | Sun | Dinner | 4 | 2021-01-23 16:39:38.363600 |

**I have tried**:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, row='smoker', col='time')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'date', 'tip', color='b')
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.twinx()
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(60)
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'date', 'total_bill', color='g')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I am unable to figure out the best way to pass the `ax.twinx()` into the secondary right y-axis plot `'tip'`.

**What I hope to achieve:**

A `sns.FacetGrid()` with `sns.lineplot`s where the features; `'total_bill'` on the left-y-axis, `'tip'` on the right-y-axis.
A green line represents the `'total_bill'` fluctuations, a blue line representing the `'tip'` fluctuations to the scale of each respective y-axis feature.

Comment: you're going to want to map a custom function that deals with the axes twinning http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html#using-custom-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a custom plotting function that create the twin axes and plots the desired output on this newly created axes:

```py
def twin_lineplot(x,y,color,**kwargs):
    ax = plt.twinx()
    sns.lineplot(x=x,y=y,color=color,**kwargs, ax=ax)

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, row='smoker', col='time')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'date', 'tip', color='b')
g.map(twin_lineplot, 'date', 'total_bill', color='g')
g.fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For the case above, if I included the code `g.add_legend()` and passed labels to `g.map(sns.lineplot, 'date', 'tip', color='b', label='label1')` and `g.map(twin_lineplot, 'date', 'total_bill', color='g', label='label2')`  it separately displays the legend for the lines. Any suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819460/normalizing-legend-appearance-when-combining-sns-facetgrid-with-custom-functio